# Show upper-part of adaptive card

Tags: node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards

I have this very long "form" using adaptive card. Using CardFactory, the bot framework, based on my understanding, can render the card and my bot can display it for my user to fill in the necessary details.

The end of my form (in which I'll use instead of the word adaptive card), has a submit button for user to click whenever all fields are filled in. And while everything works the way I want it to be, its not really user friendly in a sense that what user sees after showing the form is the bottom part of it. User has to scroll for a bit to go up and see the first part of the form.

My question is: Is there anyway I could help user experience by showing the upper-part/top most part of the form? Is that possible in bot framework?

Like if the bot sends successive messages, does the framework allows to show the first messages first, before the last part. THANK YOU!

PS. I use NodeJS for my bot framework, read the documentation but can't find one that dwells deeply about adaptive cards.

Please see images below:

[image: Before]

[image: After]

How do I make the first framework to show the first image before the end part which is in the second image.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the "ShowCard" action? It basically lets you collapse part of your card, and only open it when a user clicks on a button. That way you could possibly group your card into sections and show each one at a time. See [here](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Action.ShowCard.html) for more.

Another option in future is the new ToggleVisibility action in AdaptiveCards 1.2, but it's only if your client supports 1.2. (e.g. it's only available in [Developer Preview for Teams right now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/dev-preview/developer-preview-features#adaptive-12-support) (so very likely coming in future, but not available at the moment))

Comment: Aleimar, was this useful for you?

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment @Hilton . While I understand the mechanics of "ShowCard", I don't want my user to click showcard for say after 3-4 textbox. Also, the fields are required and showcard might hinder user (or make bad experience) if they can't see all required items without clicking button for showcard.

Comment: I have another possibility in mind, but I've never tested this.... It might be possible to make like a "wizard" scenario, with a "page 1" and a "page 2". Basically, it's possible, depending on where your bot is used, to -replace- one card with another card. So, scenario is: send "page 1", user submits, save data in the bot, replace "page 1" with "page 2", user submits, save combined data and proceed. Would something like that be a valid option? If so, you'll want to look at the "update" process for bot messages. I'm not sure if it''s a safe approach though, jsut a thought...

Comment: I considered that a possibility, but I don't want user to click submit then click submit again and so forth .. 

I guess the framework doesn't provide some control for programmers to manipulate bubbleheads/cards (if the case would be a very long bubble message). Hope this would be available in the future soon though.

Comment: nope, not much  for this kind of scenario yet unfortunately, at least not to my knowledge